# How can I spot the Winterbash-related mischief going on?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2015

I've noticed some strange behaviour going on since Winterbash has started. How can I spot this behaviour before it turns into a serious issue?

How is this behaviour related to hats?

Comment: I'm already confused: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34288092/random-crashes-with-array-c

Comment: Sorry, at what @MartinJames?

Comment: In that comment thread, I ended up no knowing if I was trolling, whether I was being trolled or what day it is:)

Comment: @MartinJames wow.... just.... wow man

Comment: *I've noticed some strange behavior... ...how can I spot it?* Wait what?

Comment: Some strange behaviour going on -> Sun Wukong badge applying to this post :P

Answer (score 28):

## Hats are fun!

But low quality posts, and off-topic mischief are not.

Here's a list of the common hats that may cause mischief and how to spot it:

You can take a look at the [full list here](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com) of (non secret)hats here.

- **Timey Wimey**: this hat is received by editing old posts, so you may find users making pointless edits just to get it.
- **Thalia & Melpomene**: These hats are received from reopening/undeleting and closing/deleting respectively. You might find users making bad calls simply for the hat. Doing so can result in bans, so users should only do it legitimately.
- **Greeter**: Like **Timey Wimey**, you may find users editing new posts with pointless changes.
- **Hairboat's Revenge**: This is the one that I found clogging up chat transcripts a lot. This badge is earned by commenting on any of [Jon Ericson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1438/jon-ericson?tab=topactivity)'s posts, these comments are usually cleared by CMs or Mods soon, but nonetheless.
- **Speedy Delivery**: This badge is earned by answering a question less than half an hour after it was posted, and subsequently earning at least +3 and being accepted. As such, you may find users posting low-quality answers within that half an hour, and doing the rest afterward.
- **Living in the Future**: This badge is earned by selfie-answering a pre-Winterbash post of yours, so you may find users answering their own old, potentially dead posts with new stuff. This is not necessarily mischief, but can become so if posted with little more than required as on-topic.
- **Auld Lang Syne**: Posting a chat message within twelve hours of UTC New Years Day that gets starred. While not an issue now, chatrooms may find themselves star-flooded on the night.
- **Sun Wukong**: Here's the one to watch out for: A hidden hat earned by a meta post with `-5/+5`. Users may post crap on meta that gets downvoted solely for the hat. Some SE sites have allowed this, others have not. This may be something that gets Meta'd later.
- **Vote Early/Vote Often**: Earned by voting a considerable 250 times in 7 days.
  As the vote allowance for 7 days is 280, this is nearly equivalent to capping every day. As such you may see people wasting upvotes and downvotes where they normally wouldn't.
- **I'm Batman**: This hat is earned by editing a question that gets reopened after doing so. Edited questions end up in the review queue, so users looking to get this badge may cause an influx of questions into the Reopen queue. As for questions getting legitimately reopened, some users get in while the question circulates in the Review Queue and make pointless edits to get the badge.
- **007**: A hidden hat earned by posting an answer with 0 comments on a question with 0 comments, and the answer reach score of 7.
- **Onion Knight**: A hidden hat that's awarded for asking a question that is being on top the Hot Network Questions list.
- **Odinson**: A hidden hat earned by flagging a post as a duplicate before it is closed by someone else, or (for a tag gold badge user) dup-hammering a question with initial duplicate votes from other users.
- **Archimedes**: A hidden hat awarded for guessing a secret hat

Comment: Is Onion Knight a GoT reference or a Dark Souls reference?

Comment: @mikeTheLiar we believe it could also be a Final Fantasy reference. The MSE post on Secret Hats contains a little more tinfoil, if you're interested.

Comment: For anyone else wondering, the [secret hat post is here this year](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270789/winter-bash-2015-secret-hats).